# Convert PDF to PNG without output file extension using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

It is simple to convert PDF file to PNG:

```
convert input.pdf -colorspace RGB -resize 800 output.png
```

However I have to skip extension in the file name, so I have tried with:

```
convert input.pdf -colorspace RGB -resize 800 output
```

but it generates me PDF file. How can I specify PDF type with `convert` argument ?

```
-type PNG
```

does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution:

```
convert input.pdf -colorspace RGB -resize 800 png:output
```

This creates a PNG file named `output`.

Comment: Doing the opposite with input.png and pdf:output doesn't seem to work